# Ionic Modal not opening (TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined)?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am making an ionic + angularJs app, for Android to be specific. I don't know why, but in my so named `homeController`, whenever I tried to call a function to show me a `$ionicModal`, it gives me an error...

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined at
>   Scope.$scope.openModal (homeModule.js:18) at new 
>   (homeModule.js:59) at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:11994) at
>   $get.extend.instance (ionic.bundle.js:16247) at ionic.bundle.js:15502
>   at forEach (ionic.bundle.js:8155) at nodeLinkFn
>   (ionic.bundle.js:15501) at compositeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:14887) at
>   publicLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:14766) at
>   IonicModule.controller.self.appendViewElement (ionic.bundle.js:47324)

My controller looks like this (the start of it):

```
app.controller('homeController', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $state, $ionicLoading, $rootScope, $ionicModal, mapFactory){
    // Load the modal from the given template URL
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/loginModal.html', function($ionicModal) {
      $scope.modal = $ionicModal;
      console.log($scope.modal);
    }, {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up',
      backdropClickToClose: false,
      hardwareBackButtonClose: false,
      focusFirstInput: true
    });
    $scope.openModal = function() {
        $scope.modal.show();
    };
    $scope.closeModal = function() {
        $scope.modal.hide();
    };
```

I have tried already many different ways to make the modal open, the funny thing is, whenever I go to a new $state, and go back, it opens... But not when I refresh the page. Also, I did a `console.log($scope.modal)` to see if my variable was being set, and the result was:

```
ionic.Utils.inherit.child {focusFirstInput: true, unfocusOnHide: true, focusFirstDelay: 600, backdropClickToClose: false, hardwareBackButtonClose: false…}$el: JQLite[1]animation: "slide-in-up"backdropClickToClose: falseel: div.modal-backdropfocusFirstDelay: 600focusFirstInput: truehardwareBackButtonClose: falsemodalEl: ion-modal-view.modalscope: ChildScopeunfocusOnHide: trueviewType: "modal"__proto__: ionic.Utils.inherit.Surrogate
```

Can anyone please help me on this one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means `$scope.modal` was not created - you call to `fromTemplateUrl` isn't right.  The second parameter is the modal options and you're passing a callback.

The documentation provides a [good example](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/).

In your case, the call to `fromTemplateUrl` should look more like this:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/loginModal.html', {
  scope: $scope,
  animation: 'slide-in-up',
  backdropClickToClose: false,
  hardwareBackButtonClose: false,
  focusFirstInput: true
}).then(function(modal) {
  $scope.modal = modal;
  console.log($scope.modal);
});
```

Comment: I did as you said, but unfortunately it didn't work... I am kind of a newbie on Ionic, but from what i know, and the documentation i saw, it is right... But still, it shows me that "Cannot read property 'show' of undefined"... Maybe it has something to do with AngularJS? Im using the ionic.bundle.js... And still, the console.log shows me the modal defined, but i cant open it

Comment: I think i found a temporary solution, as i don't think it is the best practice... I got the $ionicModal to open while i was still defining it, inside the .then function of it... But i don't know if it is best to do this

Comment: I had a similar problem because I hadn't add the plugin: cordova plugin add https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker.git

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the fix. I was trying to open the modal from inside a 'if' statement, as soon as i took it off from the 'if', it worked perfectly fine. Anyways, thank you Brad.